# Real and imaginary parts of a complex number

Tags: complex

I would like to find the real and imaginary parts of $x + y$ in terms of polar coordinates.

Here is code:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[x + y], {x, y}, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]
```

How can I add the assumption that $Abs[x]$ equals to $Abs[y]$?

For example this code does not work:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[x + y], {x, y}, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}, 
Assumptions -> Abs[x] == Abs[y]]
```

Comment: By the above assumption, I expect to obtain: Re[x + y] = Abs[x] (Cos[Arg[x]] + Cos[Arg[y]])

Comment: Or, how can I change the code to obtain Re[x + y] = Abs[x] (Cos[Arg[x]] + Cos[Arg[y]]), by the assumption that Abs[x] = Abs[y]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would

```
Simplify[
  ComplexExpand[Re[x + y], {x, y}, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}], 
  Assumptions -> Abs[x] == Abs[y]]
```

> ```
> Abs[y] (Cos[Arg[x]] + Cos[Arg[y]])
> ```

work for you?

Comment: Very good. Thank you.

Comment: @To Be - The algorithms give `Abs[y]` rather than the equivalent `Abs[x]`; however, if the difference is important to you, you could try playing with the `ComplexityFunction` for `FullSimplify` or just use a rule `/. Abs[y] -> Abs[x]`